# How to remove month and days name from owl-date-time component?

Tags: html, css, angular, datepicker

I am trying to make a calendar with only days to be selected. The user should select the day it wants to pay some product.

I am using the owl-date-time component in a Angular application. Is it possible to do it somehow?

```
  <label>
    Date
    <input [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt3" [owlDateTime]="dt3">
    <owl-date-time [pickerType]="'calendar'" #dt3></owl-date-time>
  </label>
```

I am looking for something like this:

[image]

Comment: Try display none

Answer (score 0):

I use ::ng-deep and set display: none to the block I want to delete.